# Android add view blank

Tags: android

[image]

I add a view to my project like so:

```
View inflater = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_miles, null, true);

        //Add views
        LinearLayout contentDraw = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_main);
        contentDraw.addView(inflater);
```

However when I display the view I get a blank page.

Here is my view layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_miles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootMilesFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nav_miles">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_miles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Hello Miles!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_miles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I cannot seem to figure out what is happening.

Here is my code for loading the view:

```
FrameLayout mLayoutMiles = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootMilesFrag);
                                for (int i = 0; i < mLayoutMiles.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                    View v = mLayoutMiles.getChildAt(i);
                                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    v.postInvalidate();
                                }
                                mLayoutMiles.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mLayoutMiles.postInvalidate();
```

The page does show the bottom navigation panel at the top of the screen, however it does not show the edit text or the green background.

Comment: getLayoutInflater() Is it activity or fragment.

Comment: It is an activity, I added an image to the top.

Comment: Okay, If you want child layout you can use include xml itself. Here what you're doing? Are you new pie to android?

Comment: Yes this is new to me. So just include the xml in my main activity xml?

Comment: Yeah... Are you trying to interact with bottom nav or just another view ...

Comment: Just trying to show a view that is outside of my main activity xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246550/discussion-between-ackfloverstow-and-gobu-csg).